# Safari not recognizing htaccess img rewrite

Tags: php, .htaccess, server

I have several lines in my htaccess to accomplish the following:

1. rewrite a php page/script as .png
2. force user-side cache refresh for all images

My htaccess lines:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /directory/to/dynamic_image
RewriteRule ^bg\.png$ bg.php

AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .jpeg

<Files bg.png>
FileETag None
Header unset ETag
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=0, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"
Header set Pragma "no-cache"
Header set Expires "Wed, 11 Jan 1984 05:00:00 GMT"
</Files>

# DISABLE CACHING
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header set Cache-Control "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"
    Header set Pragma "no-cache"
    Header set Expires 0
</IfModule>
```

I noticed on specifically Safari, any image rewrite shows up invalid. Any idea of what might be happening? The image rewrite works fine on Chrome and other browsers.

For posterity I'll also include the php script that's being rewritten to png:

````
$imagesDir = 'img/';

$images = glob($imagesDir . '*.{jpg,jpeg,png,gif}', GLOB_BRACE);

$randomImage = $images[array_rand($images)]; // See comments


$file_out = $randomImage; // The image to return

if (file_exists($file_out)) {

   $image_info = getimagesize($file_out);

   //Set the content-type header as appropriate
   header('Content-Type: ' . $image_info['mime']);

   //Set the content-length header
   header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file_out));

   //Write the image bytes to the client
   readfile($file_out);
}
else { // Image file not found

    header($_SERVER["SERVER_PROTOCOL"] . " 404 Not Found");

}?>```


Any help appreciated. Thanks!
````

Answer (score 0):

Identified the fix: The content-length header was the issue in the PHP. Once removed the script performs as intended. Thanks!